# How do I autoconnect ExpressVPN on startup?

Tags: raspbian, kodi, retropie

Dear people of the internet,

Since a few days I have been messing around with my RBP 3B+. I installed Retropie, which is my bootable program. Altough I want to use ExpressVPN before starting Kodi without using Terminal, it seemed a good idea to auto-connect this application. I already used the auto-connect command, but for some reason it does not work. 
So, I want to run the command 'expressvpn connect' after starting Retropie.
Does anybody know a solution?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Could you add a little more detail to your question? ie. what exactly _was_ the "auto-connect" command you used, and what exactly is your question? is it "how do i run something after starting retropie" or "how do I run the 'expressvpn connect' command", etc. Thankyou.

Comment: Sorry for my late response.
My question is: how do I run the command 'expressvpn connect' when I start retropie?

Comment: Edit: I put the command in /etc/rc.local/, but it only seems to run the command when I open the Terminal (Putty)

Comment: Ok. try using `systemd`. Try searching for [systemd start service after another](https://www.google.com/search?q=systemd+start+service+after+another)